# Ambiguous Column Name When Selecting From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server 2012 and during the selection of UserName from different tables I get the following error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Ambiguous column name 'UserName'

```
SELECT *
FROM   Signup,
       Pers_D,
       Edu_D,
       Dep_S
WHERE  UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%';
```

Comment: you know what would help?, if you posted the actual query you are using

Comment: quick respose...now check

Comment: well, how many of those tables have a `UserName` column?, I mean, the error message is pretty clear

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: all of them have UserName,because 'UserName'  is and ID of each person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be accomplished in that way. Comma says - you are trying to join those tables. Not union.

You are getting error `Ambiguous column name 'UserName'` because several tables have column with that name and server does not understand where to apply this filter.

In simple statements solution could look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Signup as s
WHERE  s.UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM   Pers_D as p
WHERE  p.UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM   Edu_D as e
WHERE  e.UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM   Dep_S as d
WHERE  d.UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%'
```

This is literally what you are attempting to do.

But your approach is leading you somewhere there:

```
SELECT s.*, p.*, e.*, d.*
FROM   Signup s
INNER JOIN Pers_D p ON p.??? = s.???
INNER JOIN Edu_D e on e.??? = ???
INNER JOIN Dep_S d on d.??? = ???
WHERE  [???].UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%' ---<<< ambiguity: s.UserName? p.UserName? e.UserName? d.UserName?
```

Comment: thumbs up emoticon for you @Ivan Starostin. I have solved my Problem by the help of `YOU`.

Answer (score 1):

UserName is in more than one table.  Try using an alias

I also don't see a JOIN, you will get much more than you probably expected

```
SELECT *
FROM Signup A,Pers_D B,Edu_D C,Dep_S D
WHERE A.UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%';
```

Comment: Is this answer will print all the data regarding `UserName`?

Comment: You will get all records where UserName like ...   however, since there is no join, you will get a many-to-many result

Comment: By Applying your code, i have got 112 rows else than only 1.

Comment: I suspected as much.  As I mentioned, you didn't have any joins on the other table,

Comment: As a learning excersise, I would recommend starting with 1 table which has user name, and then add another which a join

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is actually giving you a cross join, which is every row in every table TIMES every row in the other tables.  Probably not what you want.

The SELECT * is giving you every column from the 4 tables.  At least 2 of those tables have a username column.

An easy way to see the columns in the Signup table is

```
SELECT TOP 10 * from Signup
```

You can use this on each table to see which tables have UserName in them.

You can ALIAS the tables and then specify which table you want to compare the UserName to in the WHERE column.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Signup AS S,
       Pers_D AS P,
       Edu_D AS E,
       Dep_S AS D
WHERE  P.UserName LIKE '%Hwl123%';
```

Unless the CROSS JOIN is what you were going for, you really should rewrite that query as a series of JOINs based on columns that the tables share.

Comment: I want to get 1 answser, means only that data which is regarding to the  ' UserName Hwl123 '  but your answered quries prints all the data in database.